# Given $S_x = X_1 + \cdots X_n$ and $S_y = Y_1 + \cdots Y_n$ prove that $P(S_x \neq S_y) \leq \sum_{k=1}^n P(X_k \neq Y_k)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, solution-verification, random-variables, induction

Given $X_1, \cdots , X_n , Y_1, \cdots Y_n$ one dimensional random variables in a probability space , we define $S_x = X_1 + \cdots X_n$ and $S_y = Y_1 + \cdots Y_n$. Prove that $\displaystyle P(S_x \neq S_y) \leq \sum_{k=1}^n P(X_k \neq Y_k)$.

I want to verify if my proof is correct **only using induction** (I already know a proof without induction so I am not interested in another proof).

Case $n=1$ is trivial. Assume is true for $n$ and let's prove it for $n+1$.

Define $S_x ' = S_x + X_{n+1}$ and $S_y' = S_x + Y_{n+1}$. Then

\begin{align*}
P(S_x' \neq S_y') &\leq P(S_x \neq S_y \; \land X_{n+1} \neq Y_{n+1}) \; \; \; \text{ (Monotony of P)}\\
&=P(S_x \neq S_y)P(X_{n+1} \neq Y_{n+1}) \; \; \; \text{ (Independence by construction)}\\
&\leq  \sum_{k=1}^n P(X_k \neq Y_k)P(X_{n+1} \neq Y_{n+1}) \; \; \; \text{ (Induction hypothesis)}\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}P(X_k \neq Y_k)
\end{align*}

Where the last inequality is true because note that $0\leq P(X_{n+1} \neq Y_{n+1}) \leq 1$ so $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n  P(X_k \neq Y_k)P(X_{n+1} \neq Y_{n+1}) \leq  \sum_{k=1}^nP(X_k \neq Y_k) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}P(X_k \neq Y_k)$

Closing the induction and proving the result.

My only doubts about my proof are the first inequality, because I am not 100% sure that the event $S_x' \neq S_y'$ is equal or is contained in $S_x \neq S_y \; \land X_{n+1} \neq Y_{n+1}$. Any corrections (if they are possible) are appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that the correct implication is $$\{S'_x \neq S'_y\} \subseteq \{S_x \neq S_y\} \cup \{X_{n+1} \neq Y_{n+1}\}. $$ (Consider the contrapositive!) Induction will work quite smoothly with this, and this is essentially the same as the union bound.